# Import statement runs well in Pycharm, but not in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

Here is the structure of my project

```
project
  /package_one
    /dir_one
     __init__.py   
     Class_one.py
   __init__.py
   main.py
   /Frontend
     ...
   /Backend
     ...(need to import from package_one)
```

I need to import `package_one` as a library to my backend, and also I need it to run separately with `main.py`

In my `/project/package_one/__init__.py`

```
from package_one.dir_one import Class_one
```

In my `proejct/package_one/main.py`
I tried both

```
from package_one.dir_one import Class_one
```

and

```
from dir_one import Class_one
```

Both methods above work well in Pycharm, but when I run it in the terminal with
 `python3 -m main.py` or `python3 main.py`
It prompts an error
`ModuleNotFOundError: No Module named 'package_one`

---

I tried to change the working directory by adding `sys.chdir('..')`
and change the `export PYTHONPATH=[path_to_project]` but doesn't work.

Comment: for ```/project/package_one/__init__.py```,  since you're already in the ```package_one``` dir,  you just need ```from .dir_one import Class_one```.

Comment: If I `from .dir_one import Class_one`, when I import from the `backend` folder, it shows me no module issue